# Click button on Email confermation and Reload the current Tab

Tags: html, button, tabs, html-email

In my web app(React+Node.js) when a user registers an email is sent. Now in that email, I put a button that when clicked is sent to a link. But if I have the site already open, is there a way to change that specific tab and not open another one?

Template email code:

```
<div align="center">
<div style="max-width: 680px; min-width: 500px; border: 2px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius:5px; margin-top: 20px">
    <div>
        LOGO
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: #fbfcfd; border-top: thick double #cccccc; text-align: left;">
        <div style="margin: 30px;">
            <p>
                Dear {{user.username}},                    
            </p>
            <table style="text-align: center;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form action=`http://localhost:3000/{{hash}}`>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Click Here</button>
                        </form>

                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From tab A I have a message that invites me to read email. But when I click the button the link open another Tab B. But I want the tab A to Reload or somehow to be closed.

Comment: Dont think that is possible. jQuery will only work (its not stripped) when viewed online.

Comment: surely just use an `a` tag with `target="_self"`? form/button support within emails is very poor

Comment: That would refresh the same page if it is open in the browser, right? OP wants all tabs to refresh if a **new** tab is open or closed the other ones.

Comment: No that is not possible, it will always open a new tab, or refresh the tab you are reading your webmail in.